# Javascript foreach loop go to next element on callback

Tags: javascript

```
for(var P in ReturnData.Playlist){
    var IsLoaded = false;
    if(PlayerName == "A"){
        LoadNavA(false,false,false, ReturnData.Playlist[P], function(){
            IsLoaded = true;
            alert();
        });
        }else{
        LoadNavB(false,false,false, ReturnData.Playlist[P],function(){
            IsLoaded = true;
        });
    }
    if(IsLoaded == true) continue;
}
```

This is for a music playout system. The `LoadNavA` and `LoadNavB` functions load a track to the playlist asynchronously. These elements must be in the correct order. When track 3 is loaded earlier than track 2, it first places track 3 and than track 2, but it should start loading track 3 when track 1 and 2 are already loaded.

When the callback in `LoadNavA` or `LoadNavB` is called, then the loop should go on. How?

Comment: Are you trying to load these in order? That is, are you attempting to wait to load the next one until the current one is done?

Comment: Yes these elements must be in the correct order, that is (for me) the most difficult to the whole system, when track 3 is loaded earlier than track 2, it first places track 3 and than track 2, but it has to start loading track 3 when track 1 and 2 are already loaded

Comment: OK, there's a general approach to this, which I've tried to explain below.

Comment: I'm going to put your comment in the question. I think it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that `LoadNavA` and `LoadNavB` invoke *asynchronous* operations, which can return in any order, but you're attempting to enforce some ordering. This is a problem, because your loop will have completed by the time the callbacks are actually executed, so your attempts to hold-up the processing are misguided.

What you want, instead, is a means to invoke some asynchronous operations in order. I've written a general function to accomplish this:

```
// receives a callback and the elements to iterate
function loop(list, fn) {
    if (!list || list.length <= 0)
        return;
    (function chain(i) {
        if (i >= list.length)
            return;
        fn(list[i], function() {
            chain(i + 1);
        });
    })(0);
}
```

This function assumes you're giving it a callback that will perform some operation and that that operation will kick-off the next step in the chain once it completes. To make this concrete, here is an example based off of your code.

First, a little setup, so that we can work with your example:

```
var PlayerName = "B";
var ReturnData = {};
ReturnData.Playlist = ["song1", "song2", "song3"];

function LoadNavA(b1, b2, b3, el, fn) {
    // this could be any asynchronous call (e.g. Ajax)
    // using setTimeout here for illustration
    window.setTimeout(fn, 2000);
}

var LoadNavB = LoadNavA; // for brevity
```

Now, the actual usage of `loop`:

```
loop(ReturnData.Playlist, function(song, next) {
    if (PlayerName == "A") {
        LoadNavA(false, false, false, song, function() {
            alert("LoadNavA: " + song);
            next();
        });
    } else {
        LoadNavB(false, false, false, song, function() {
            alert("LoadNavB: " + song);
            next();
        });
    }

});
```

The callback given as the second argument to `loop` will be executed once for each element in the list. It receives as arguments an element in the playlist and a function referred to as `next`. This callback is free to execute any asynchronous operations, as long as those operations invoke the `next` function once they're done. This is the mechanism by which we advance to the next element in the playlist so that the process can be repeated for every element.

Comment: This is for a music playout system, te LoadNavA and LoadNavB functions load asynchronous a track to the playlist. This foreach is to load a playlist from the server into the client playlist. When this foreach is calles, the tracks arent in the right order